# replace specific character - power query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

How can I change or remove the initial "0" from my CARS column? Type must be text.
I tried using the code below but it changed every "0". I only need to change the initial, in case I remove it.

```
#"Valor Substituído" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Personalização dicionada3","0","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"CARRO"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample below changes leading "0" in [CARS] column to instead be "CARRO"

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"CARS", type text}}),
#"Change Start" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"CARS", each if Text.StartsWith(_, "0") then Text.ReplaceRange(_, 0, 1, "CARRO") else _, type text}})
in "Change Start"
```

I think for you it becomes

```
#"Valor Substituído" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Personalização dicionada3",{{"CARS", each if Text.StartsWith(_, "0") then Text.ReplaceRange(_, 0, 1, "CARRO") else _, type text}})
```